# How to wait for a thread to finish its work

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a console application. A class (let's say Worker) does some work in a separate thread and throws an event when it finishes. But this never happens because the execution ends instantly. How can I wait for the thread to finish and handle the event after it throws?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    worker.WorkCompleted += PostProcess;
    worker.DoWork();
}

static void PostProcess(object sender, EventArgs e) { // Cannot see this happening }
```

**Edit:** Corrected the order of the statements but that was not the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've got a race condition, in that the work could finish before you register for the event. To avoid the race condition, change the order of the code so you register for the event before starting the work, then it will always be raised, no matter how fast it finishes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    worker.WorkCompleted += PostProcess;
    worker.DoWork();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

OK the question has been modified, so it looks like what you're really asking is how to wait for `PostProcess` to finish executing. There are a couple of ways to do this, but you'll have to add some more code.

The easiest way is, because events always execute on the same thread as they are raised, is to call `Thread.Join` on the thread the `Worker` class creates, e.g. assuming the thread is exposed as a property:

```
worker.Thread.Join();
```

(Although to be honest I'd probably keep the `Thread` private and expose a method called something like `WaitForCompletion` on the `Worker` class that calls it).

Alternative methods are:

1. Have a `WaitHandle`, probably a `ManualResetEvent`, in the `Worker` class which is `Set` when it completes all its work, and call `WaitOne` on it.
2. Have a `volatile bool complete` field in the `Worker` class and loop while waiting for it to be set to `true`, using `Thread.Sleep` in the loop body (this probably isn't a good solution, but it is feasible).

There are probably other options too, but that's the common ones.

Comment: here i have seen there is built in class called Worker but i found no class called Worker in .net 4.0. which version has class Worker? please let me know.

Comment: @Thomas - The `Worker` class was just the name of the class used by the OP. I assume that it is part of their framework.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried switching the order of the statements ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    worker.WorkCompleted += PostProcess;
    worker.DoWork();
}
```

WorkCompleted is an event handler and has to be set up-front. This does not get invoked by the assignment worker.WorkCompleted += PostProcess;

Comment: Thanks, but it is correct in my real code, that is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use WaitHandle class members (WaitOne, WaitAny, or WaitAll)

See [Details Here In MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Worker class should have a method that allows the client to wait for the thread to complete. That method would call the appropriate overload of `Thread.Join()` to implement the wait.  If it doesn't (and you have no way to modify the `Worker` class), it may have some method to get to the internal Thread object and you can perform the Join() on that object.

If it has neither of those, you'll need to look at (and/or post here) more details of the `Worker` class interface to see if it has an appropriate method to wait for completion.  If it doesn't have one, then you'll need your own `EventWaitHandle` object that the `PostProcess()` event handler can signal when it gets invoked.

Comment: Worker class has no Join method. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry - I answered as if the worker object was an object of the Thread class.  I've amended my answer to be more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no access to the Worker class, just add a flag that indicates when PostProcessing has done and sleep until the flag is set:

```
static bool isProcessed = false;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    worker.WorkCompleted += PostProcess;
    worker.DoWork();
    while(!isProcessed)
    {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(-1);
    }
}

static void PostProcess(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   // Cannot see this happening 
   isProcessed=true;
}
```

THis should do the trick, but I can't guarantee that it is robust without more information on your setup.

Comment: That is manual code and wastage of CPU to wait for processing to complete. WaitHandles are meant to tackle these situations.

Comment: I actually have no idea what the behavior of WaitHandle is when it is only signaled from the blocking thread, and I was too lazy to test it.  I had assume PostProcess executes on the blocked thread.  Without more information this was an easy solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `BackgroundWorker` class from the .net framework for this.

It does exactly what you want to do. In addition it handles invoking itself so no pain for you with this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(MyThreadMethod);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    Console.Read();
}

static void MyThreadMethod(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worker starts working.");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Worker works fine.");
}

static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worker has finished.");
}

static void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worker reports progress {0}", e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good candidate of using the Begin/End asynchronous pattern in your worker. So instead of just a `DoWork()` method that starts to do the work asynchronously and an event that fires when the work is complete, `Worker` would include a synchronous `Work()` method that returns the result(s) of the work, and `BeginWork()` and `EndWork()` pair that can be used for asynchronous use.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seta58yd(VS.71).aspx for some more information about this. Might be a good fit for your situation?

Comment: (Assuming you actually wrote or otherwise have access to the source code of the Worker class, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I think 
Application.Run
after initializing your thread. and on completion call
Application.Exit